# How to replace one string on multiple titles

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In my Microsoft SQL Server Management if I use this query:

```
select * from Modules where ModuleTitle like '%MyOldString%'
```

I can find multiple results with different ModuleIDs like 1, 2, 5, 1257, etc.
So now, I want to backup this ModuleIDs, then change all the string "MyOldString" to "MyNewString" in all that Module Titles, how should I do ?
If change one of them, I can use:

```
update Modules set ModuleTitle = 'MyNewString' where ModuleID = 1257
```

But now, I only need to replace the string and all at one for all that in the search results, is it possible ? And I need to backup that ModuleIDs, in case I need to change them back.

Comment: you can add new column `ModuleTitleOld` on same table rather than baking it up..so you can copy `ModuleTitle` to-> `ModuleTitleOld` every time you replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update it with a replace query:
`update Modules
SET ModuleTitle = REPLACE(ModuleTitle,'MyOldString','MyNewString')
WHERE ModuleTitle like '%MyOldString%'
;`

Comment: I would recommend adding the WHERE clause as well, for performance reasons.

Comment: This query will search all places, but when I change back (in case needed), I cannot for sure change back the same number of modified. That is why I need to save all the ModuleIDs and use where to change accordingly...

Comment: I can copy all the ModuleIDs in the results. Is it possible to change it back like: update Modules
SET ModuleTitle = REPLACE(ModuleTitle,'MyNewString','MyOldString')
WHERE ModuleID = 1 and 2 and 5 and 7 and 1527 ... ?
;

Comment: change it to WHERE ModuleID IN (1,2,5,7,1527)

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

First, you can easily change the string using the same WHERE expression as you do for searching.

```
  select * from Modules where ModuleTitle like '%MyOldString%'
```

You can update using

```
 update Modules set ModuleTitle = 'MyNewString' 
 where ModuleTitle like '%MyOldString%'
```

As far as backup, where do you want to back the records up to?   Just title or the full record?

One option would be to write a trigger, and automatically back things up into a separate table (containing ID, old title, and an update date).   The benefit of the trigger would be the records get logged every time the title changes, not just when your code does it.

```
CREATE TABLE Module_backup 
(Module_ID int,
 oldtitle VARCHAR(200),
 updDate DATETIME DEFAULT getDate()
)
```

Add a trigger to the table.   Basically, in the trigger, if both INSERTED and DELETED are populated (i.e. an update operation),

```
INSERT INTO Module_backup(Module_id,oldtitle)
SELECT Module_Id,ModuleTitle FROM DELETED
```

Comment: I think in my case I need to replace string, as mentioned. For back up, I just need to be able to copy all that ModuleID numbers, so that if later I want to change everything back, I just use the similar querry for all that numbers.

Comment: A trigger would be your best option.   Create a table to hold the backup record and populate it via the trigger...

Comment: Look up triggers on Google or in Books Online.   Basically, a trigger is a piece of code you attach to the table, and it gets called after certain events, such as a record being updated.   I added a rough idea in the answer as to what your trigger will do..